# Typescript: Code looks the same, but it's generating an error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
  interface Product {
    [key: string]: {
      options?: Record<string, string>
    }
  }
```

so:

```
  state: Product
  ...
  state = state ?? {}
  state[sku] = state[sku] ?? {}
  state[sku].options = state[sku].options ?? {}
  state[sku].options[id] = e.target.value       // this line breaks
```

The line highlighted above is saying that `state[sku].options` could be undefined, of course I know is not undefined, since I'm checking on the line before.

However, this code does exactly the same, and works.

```
  const newState = state ?? {}
  const slice = newState[sku] ?? {}
  slice.options = slice.options ?? {}
  slice.options[id] = e.target.value
```

so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a limitation of Typescript. If you create a type like below:

```
type T = { [key: string]: string | undefined };
```

And then try:

```
var sth: T = { prop: "abc" };
sth.prop.slice()
```

you'll get an error since the definition of `sth` will still be general `T`. It doesn't care that one of props of `sth` is actually a `string` (that is, typescript won't constrain the type of `sth`).

But when you do:

```
var u = { prop: "abc" };
u.prop.slice()
```

The type of `u` will be constrained to

```
{
  prop: string
}
```

so no error here.

Comment: @Pablo you've found a workaround yourself. Introduce an auxiliary variable and work on it: `var slice = state[sku] = state[sku] ?? {}` instead of bare `state[sku]`.